# Is there a generally accepted distinction between saying "an operation in a set" versus "an operation on a set"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, definition

When I first learned the axioms (laws) of a group, they were

1. Closure
2. Associativity
3. Identity
4. Inverse

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html

I've noticed many authors omit the *closure* axiom.  In particular [BBFSK](https://archive.org/stream/MyStuff38/Behnke%2C%20Bachmann%2C%20Fladt%20%26%20Suss%20%5BEds.%5D%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1%2C%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra%5BMIT%20Press%2C%20555p%5D) IB-1.2.1 (page 111) say the group operation is defined *in* the set.  Does the expression: *A set together with an operation define **in it**...* specifically mean that the operation has values in the set?  That is, does the use of *in it* imply closure?  In contrast, would the expression: *A set together with an operation define **on it**...* suggest the possibility that the operation has values not in the set?

Notice that Mathworld says:

> The operation with respect to which a group is defined is often called the "group operation," and a set is said to be a group "under" this operation.

Does the use of the term "under" imply the possibility that the operation my have values not in the set?

An example that comes to mind where one may wish to distinguish between an operation in a set, versus an operation on a set is the distinction between vector addition, which has arguments and values in the same vector space, whereas the inner product has values in the scalar field over which the vector space is defined.  So vector addition would be defined *in* the vector space, and the inner product is an operation *on* the vector space.

This is a distinction I have noticed, but have never seen explicitly formalized.

Comment: I think that if you look deeper into the 555 page book you reference then at page 167 it seems that a "binary operation on $G$" is a function whose domain is $G\times G$ but whose range is not specified, and so the author does need an axiom (which he calls V) to ensure that the values of the function lie in $G$ (closure). Personally I think that's odd, and that @David A. Craven's answer is the way to go!

Comment: I wish I had access to the German language original.  Translations are notorious when it comes to linguistic subtleties.  Not to disparage the august accomplishments of the superlative  translator.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "binary operation in $G$" until your post quoting a translation of a book. It might not be standard/common mathematical English at all.

Answer (score 5):

Usually the binary operation is defined $\cdot\,:G\times G\to G$, in which case closure is inherent to the definition and need not be specifically included.

Usually I would say that a set with a binary operation **on** it either **forms** a group, or is a group **with respect to** the operation. I have never heard anyone refer to an operation *in* a set before this translation, like Mark S. in the comment, and I suspect it's a translation error rather than anything else. I would claim that there would be no mathematical dinstinction between them.

The use of the term under is to mean that the set need not form a group under a different operation.

Comment: I agree that the use of the term "under" has the connotation you give.  My main question is the distinction between saying an "operation **on** a set", versus "an operation **in** a set".

Comment: There is no distinction to me.

Comment: If you add your last comment to your answer, assuming no-one presents an authoritative contradiction to it, I will accept the answer.